# How not to include first line in another p class

Tags: css, html

Hi i want to know how not to include first-line 
like this

```
p:first-line
{
    font-family: georgia;
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

in this

```
 p.test7{
color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: Could you try reformulating? I'm having trouble understanding what you mean.

Comment: It looks like you might just want `p.test7:first-line`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
p:not(.test7):first-line {
    font-family: georgia;
    color: #FF0000;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```